# Making the most out of two 5-digit numbers

Tags: math, uuid

not sure if this is the right place, but I AM sure there are people amongst you who would be able to give me a good insight in the following:

Consider [this](http://glimwormbeacons.com/learn/what-makes-an-ibeacon-an-ibeacon/) description of iBeacon's payload.
As far as I understand there is one UUID that unifies a group of beacons, and a 'minor' and 'major' value that differentiates the beacons within that group.

Now, I want to use the iBeacon protocol for one of my apps. I would have to use that UUID to uniquely identify my app, leaving me just the *minor* and *major* values to somehow uniquely identify each running instance of that app.

Both the **Minor** and the **Major** parameter are a

> (uint16_t)

which I just understand from the comments is a number between 0 and 65,535.

**How do I optimally use those two numbers to create as many unique numbers as possible?**

Thank you so much for your consideration.

Comment: I think you should probably consider these numbers in binary rather than decimal. With 16 binary digits/bits, you can represent the values 0 to 65535. With 32 bits you can represent this number squared, which I think is around 4 billion.

Comment: but then again, 99999*99999= 9.999.800.001

Comment: You can't use 99,999 because the maximum value of uint16_t is 65,535.

Comment: @Sjakelien, there is no direct way to tell how many decimal digits can be represented with a given number of binary digits. a `uint16_t` doesn't mean 5 decimal digits (0 to 99999), it means 2^16 different numbers (0 to 65535). In the end, there are a fixed number of values that can be represented by 32 bits. There is no clever way of splicing them up into smaller chunks that will increase this number. One bit gives you two possible values (0 or 1) and every bit after this doubles the amount you could represent before.

Comment: So, basically, I am stuck with the 4 billion that you, Eigenchris,  mentioned, right?

Comment: @Sjakelien: Are you trying to create a consumer or producer of iBeacon data?

Comment: @Bill Lynch: Both, but I think the challenge is on the producer/transmitter side

Comment: @Sjakelien, that is correct. The way the website phrases it, the major value might allow you to use one `uint16_t` to identify up to 2^16 different stores, and the minor value would let you use another `uint16_t` to identify up to 2^16 different nodes at a given store. In total, this is (2^16)*(2^16) = 2^32 = about 4 billion unique identifiers.

Comment: OK, well, thanks. You might want to phrase that as an answer, so I can reward you for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to understand here is that having `n` binary digits/bits will allow you to represent `2^n` different numbers. One bit lets you represent two values (0 or 1). Each additional bit doubles the amount you could represent before.

- one bit lets you represent two (2 = 2^1) values, `0` `1`, i.e. zero to one
- two bits lets you represent four (2*2 = 2^2) values, `00` `01` `10` `11`, i.e. zero to three
- three bits gives you eight (2*2*2 = 2^3) values, `000` `001` `010` ... `110` `111`, i.e. zero to seven
- sixteen bits  lets you represent 2^16 values, i.e. zero to 65535

A `uint16_t` gives you 16 bits to work with, so the amount of numbers you can represent is fixed at 2^16.

Two `uint16_t` will give you 32 bits to work with, which lets you represent 2^32 = 4,294,967,296 = about 4 billion different numbers.

There is no clever way of splicing up the bits into smaller chunks that will increase this number. If I divided 16 bits into, say, a 10-bit part and a 6-bit part, the 10-bit part would give me 2^10 numbers and the 6-bit part would give me 2^6 numbers. In total, that's still (2^10)*(2^6) = 2^(10+6) = 2^16 different numbers.